# Numbered file renaming algorithm

Tags: algorithm, asp-classic

The question is marked as ASP classic but an algorithm solution is ok.

I have the following set of files which are sequentially numbered:

1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg ... X.jpg

I need a function which will take as input two filenames, the fromFile and toFile parameter, and which needs to rename all needed files in such a way that the from file is moved in the sequence before the toFile and the files in between renumbered.

Examples:

Moving 1.jpg onto 4.jpg should do the following:

- rename 1.jpg to 1.jpg.temp
- rename 2.jpg to 1.jpg
- rename 3.jpg to 2.jpg
- rename 1.jpg.temp to 3.jpg
- other files are unaffected by the operation

Moving 4.jpg to 2.jpg should do the following:

- rename 4.jpg to 4.jpg.tmp
- rename 3.jpg to 4.jpg
- rename 2.jpg to 3.jpg
- rename 1.jpg to 2.jpg
- rename 4.jpg.tmp to 1.jpg
- other files are unaffected

As input i have an array of strings containing filenames and the two filenames to/from.

Can you tell me what is the best approach to the file renaming?

Comment: Well looping over the files, examining their names and making the change is the only way (or looping adding them to a sortable collection then renaming). As this is asp then presumably > 1 person could trigger this so what happens if they both do it at the same time. Perhaps fixed names and an order defined in a txt/xml/db would be better

Comment: Yes I know, but i have a task to add this feature to an old app which does not even have a DB, and they used the sequantial numbers for files ... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief approach, considering all your files will be named numeric.jpg, you're going to have to build your own functions though:

`FileExists(Filename)`
`RenameFile(OriginalFilename,NewFilename)`

```vbs
<%

Input1 = Request.Form("file1")
Input2 = Request.Form("file2")

'gets digits only
Input1Digit = Left(Input1,Instr(Input1,".")) 
Input2Digit = Left(Input2,Instr(Input2,".")) 


'is file1 less than file2?             
If Input1Digit < Input2Digit Then    

    'loop through the digits frontwards 1 to 5
    For x = Input1Digit to Input2Digit    

        'if the first loop?
        If cStr(x) = cStr(Input1Digit) Then 

            'see if file exists here
            If FileExists(Input1) Then 
                FileRename(Input1, Input1 & ".temp") 'Rename the file here [From, To]
                OriginalFileExists = True
            Else
                FileRename(Input1, Input1Digit & ".jpg"
                OriginalFileExists = False
            End If

        'if not on the first loop?
        Else        

            'did the original file exist '.temp'
            If OriginalFileExists Then 
                NewFileName = cInt(x) - 1
            Else
                NewFileName = cInt(x)
            End If    

            'rename each file here
            RenameFile(x & ".jpg", NewFileName & ".jpg")

        End If    
    Next 

Else


    'loop through the digits more to less 5 to 1
    For x = Input1Digit to Input2Digit STEP -1    

        'if the first loop?
        If cStr(x) = cStr(Input1Digit) Then 

            'see if file exists here
            If FileExists(Input1) Then 
                FileRename(Input1, Input1 & ".temp") 'Rename the file here [From, To]
                OriginalFileExists = True
            Else
                FileRename(Input1, Input1Digit & ".jpg"
                OriginalFileExists = False
            End If

        'if not on the first loop?
        Else        

            'did the original file exist '.temp'
            If OriginalFileExists Then 
                NewFileName = cInt(x) + 1
            Else
                NewFileName = cInt(x)
            End If    

            'rename each file here
            RenameFile(x & ".jpg", NewFileName & ".jpg")

        End If    
    Next 



End If
%>
```

Comment: I think this misses an End If before the last Rename file. And when i rename the .tmp file back to Input2 this works when moving for example 1 to 4. BUT it does not work when moving a file backwards 4->1. It doesnt complain in the loop but seems to do nothing.

Comment: I forgot you have to do a different FOR statement for backwords counting, the codes been updated, let me know.

Comment: almost. it misses a final rename of the tmp to the new filename but the problem is that moving a file backwards puts it before the file where you drop to, while dropping on a file after puts it after...